# Client node hanging while start

Tags: ignite

Ignite server is in a docker container and runs fine. I can connect using jdbc client and also using a Java thin client from intellij.
But my issue is when starting  a client node from intellij.
During the following code,
"Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);",

### both server and client acknowledges with the following message in console and nothing happens after that.

server:   Topology snapshot [ver=18, locNode=5f0fa7bc, servers=1, clients=1, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=6, offheap=1.8GB, heap=5.0GB]

### client: Topology snapshot [ver=18, locNode=6182dc8d, servers=1, clients=1, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=6, offheap=1.8GB, heap=5.0GB]

### I've some testing code in the client following the "Ignition.start", but it's not executing

```
IgniteCache < Integer, String > cache = Ignition.start(cfg).getOrCreateCache("HelloWorld"); // put some cache elements
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                cache.put(i, Integer.toString(i));
            }
 for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                System.out.println("Cache get:" + cache.get(i));
            }
```

---

Comment: It is possible that you have problems with communication (are 47100-47110 ports reachable client <-> server?). You can clarify this by setting log to verbose (-DIGNITE_QUIET=false) and/or by collecting thread dumps.

Comment: thanks @alamar , that was it.  Thanks again.